# SQL BigQuery : Select query with time basis

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm being asked to find the location of user on a database with time basis.
I want to select all reservation event detail for the month **March** on the specific time between 7:00 am to 10:00 am and 4:00 pm to 10:00 pm.

Big query has timestamp column as **event_timestamp**. so that we can get all the reservation event occurred during the time period 7:00 am to 10:00 am and 4:00 pm to 10:00 pm for the month of March.

How can i achieve to get the data on that specific time using event_timestamp.

```
  SELECT
  x.value.string_value AS lat,
  y.value.string_value AS lon, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) as t,
  geo.city
FROM
  `apps.analytics_185684181.*`,
  UNNEST(user_properties) AS x,
  UNNEST(user_properties) AS y
WHERE
  x.key="user_loc_lat"
  AND y.key="user_loc_lon"
  AND event_name='reservation'
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'events_20190301'
    AND 'events_20190331')
```

Has anybody an insight on how to do so?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks you. Updated the question. let me know if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why i can't use the "hour" in WHERE clause

Because WHERE clause is evaluated before SELECT is executed, so `hour` is not yet available at a time when WHERE is evaluated. If you want to simplify your query and use `hour` - you can first introduce `hour` field in inner SELECT and than use `hour` in outer SELECT as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT lat, lon, hour FROM (
SELECT
  x.value.string_value AS lat,
  y.value.string_value AS lon, 
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS hour
FROM `apps.analytics_185684181.*`,
  UNNEST(user_properties) AS x,
  UNNEST(user_properties) AS y
WHERE x.key="user_loc_lat"
  AND y.key="user_loc_lon"
  AND event_name='reservation'
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'events_20190301' AND 'events_20190331')
)
WHERE hour BETWEEN 7 AND 9 
OR hour BETWEEN 16 AND 21
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the result using **EXTRACT** Date function with **HOUR** part. It will return event timestamp hour in 24hr numbers(0-23).

[EXTRACT(part FROM date_expression)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract)

```
SELECT
  x.value.string_value AS lat,
  y.value.string_value AS lon, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS hour
FROM
  `apps.analytics_185684181.*`,
  UNNEST(user_properties) AS x,
  UNNEST(user_properties) AS y
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))>=7 
AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))<=9 AND 
  x.key="user_loc_lat"
  AND y.key="user_loc_lon"
  AND event_name='reservation'
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'events_20190301'
    AND 'events_20190331')
```

However i cant use column name **hour** with where clause like

[image]

which throwing error ***Unrecognized name: hour***

Any fix/suggestion and improvement are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is wrong with using `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))` in WHERE clause?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. But i just want to know why i can't use the "hour" in WHERE clause.

Comment: because WHERE clause is evaluated before SELECT is executed, so `hour` is not yet available at a time when WHERE is evaluated - make sense? if you want to simplify your query and use `hour` - you can first introduce `hour` field in inner SELECT and than use `hour` in outer SELECT - see my answer for how you can do this

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot it. I will create nested sql query. Thanks.